# Node JS client doesn't receive MQTT messages when too many messages are published by the broker in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I have a `NodeJS` client which subscribes to a [Mosquito MQTT broker](https://mosquitto.org/). The `QoS` is set to 1. But when broker sends multiple messages simultaneously on many different topics (and to all these topics, the `NodeJS` client is subscribed), the client's code is not able to receive the messages. I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) library on client side and the message-listening code goes like this:

```
public_client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  console.log(message);
}
```

It does receive some messages but not all. To verify that this is a problem on the client side, I also subscribed to the messages from [MQTT.fx](https://mqttfx.jensd.de/) and it was able to receive the messages successfully, even with `QoS` set to 0 in MQTT.fx.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you please share how you're sending the message. Also can you confirm that your message listener is subscribing to all topics?

Comment: You seem to have isolated the problem to your code. We will not be able to help unless you show your code, or at least critical parts of it.